# MassTransit specify serializer when sending scheduled message

Tags: c#, masstransit

We are using a custom serializer for our MassTransit messages. However, the scheduled messages feature only allows JSON or XML. The scheduler also uses a specific set of extension methods to send the message, and I don't see any way to specify the serializer when using those methods.

Specifically, I am using the [Schedule a message from the bus](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/scheduling/scheduling-api.html#scheduling-a-message-from-the-bus) feature.

Answer (score 0):

The Quartz message scheduler support in MassTransit only supports XML and JSON.

If your transport natively supports scheduling, you can use that instead of Quartz with any message serializer. For instance, RabbitMQ has a delayed exchange plug-in, ActiveMQ supports scheduling, as does Azure Service Bus. I think even SQS has the ability to specify a delay. So those are some alternatives to using Quartz, but your requirements may dictate the use of Quartz, in which case the built-in support for MassTransit will not meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks Chris. We are using Quartz for the recurring schedule features, and I've created a scheduler service based on the MassTransit.QuartzIntegration example. I'm relatively new to MassTransit, but I could have sworn I saw a way to override the serializer when using the regular `Send` or `Publish` methods. Is that correct or did I imagine that?

Comment: Not for send or publish, but for a specific receive endpoint that is correct.